# Change default main program with Setting

Tags: c#

How do I change the default startup program when I launch my program, but only if a setting says so?

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more information. Is your program initiating the execution of another program and depending on a config setting? What do you mean?

Comment: I have a .settings file, I want it to open a specific form dependant upon that a setting in the .settings file.

Comment: Modify the program.cs so the target of `Application.Run` changes based on the setting found.

Answer (score 2):

**program.cs**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  //
  // read your setting, and store it to a variable, such as "applicationName"
  //

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleRenderingDefault(False);
  switch (applicationName)
  {
    case "firstapp":
      Application.Run(new App1());
      break;
    case "secondapp":
      Application.Run(new App2());
      break;
    default:
      Application.Run(new Form1());
      break;
  }
}
```

Unless I've completely missed the mark.